# InvalidConfigurationRequest: A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I copy-paste the part of my `main.tf` file:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "servers" {
  name        = "allowservers"
  description = "Allow TCP:8080 inbound traffic to servers"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ubuntu" {
  image_id        = "ami-053b0d53c279acc90"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.servers.id]

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Hello, World" > index.html
              nohup busybox httpd -f -p ${var.server_port} &
              EOF
   # Required when using a launch configuration with an ASG.
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "my-vpc" {
}

data "aws_subnets" "my-vpc-subnets" {
    filter {
      name = "vpc-id"
      values = [data.aws_vpc.my-vpc.id]
    }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ubuntu_scaling" {
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.ubuntu.name
  vpc_zone_identifier = data.aws_subnets.my-vpc-subnets.ids

  target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.asg.arn]
  health_check_type = "ELB"

  min_size = 2
  max_size = 10

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "terraform-asg-ubuntu"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}

resource "aws_lb" "ubuntu-lb" {
    name = "terraform-asg-ubuntu"
    load_balancer_type = "application"
    subnets = data.aws_subnets.my-vpc-subnets.ids
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "ubuntu-lb-listener" {
    load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.ubuntu-lb.arn
    port = 80
    protocol = "HTTP"

    #By default, return a simple 404 page
    default_action {
      type = "fixed-response"

      fixed_response {
        content_type = "text/plain"
        message_body = "404:ups"
        status_code = 404
      }
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "alb" {
  name = "terraform-asg-ubuntu"
  vpc_id   = data.aws_vpc.my-vpc.id
  # Allow inbound HTTP requests
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # Allow all outbound requests
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "asg" {
  name     = "terraform-asg-example"
  port     = var.server_port
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = data.aws_vpc.my-vpc.id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200"
    interval            = 15
    timeout             = 3
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "asg" {
    listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.ubuntu-lb-listener.arn
    priority = 100

    condition {
      path_pattern {
        values = ["*"]
      }
    }
    action {
      type = "forward"
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.asg.arn
    }
}
```

It generates - when I run `terraform apply` - below error:

```
│ Error: creating ELBv2 application Load Balancer (terraform-asg-ubuntu): InvalidConfigurationRequest: A load balancer cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same Availability Zone
│       status code: 400, request id: 44b2abdb-a321-4f1e-bd6f-4b87aa943477
│
│   with aws_lb.ubuntu-lb,
│   on main.tf line 172, in resource "aws_lb" "ubuntu-lb":
│  172: resource "aws_lb" "ubuntu-lb" {
```

I am using also `vpc` module in `modules.tf` file:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "5.0.0"
  name = "my-vpc"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs             = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1f"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24"]

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  enable_vpn_gateway = true

  tags = {
    Terraform = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

With a lot of debugging still I do not how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `public_subnets` from the `vpc` module in your `aws_lb`:

```
resource "aws_lb" "ubuntu-lb" {
    name = "terraform-asg-ubuntu"
    load_balancer_type = "application"
    subnets = module.vpc.public_subnets
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.alb.id]
}
```